# See chmod permissions in windows?

Tags: windows, chmod

I'm developing a site on my local environment and I'm running windows. I need to set `chmod` file permissions (eg 666, 777, etc). Is there a way in Windows to see file permissions as chmod numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows file-security model is very different from the (old?) simple Unix approach.

In Windows you can define the access per user, per group, even per computer, and there are many more access-types than just read, write and execute.

If you want to support all Windows file-security aspects, take a look at the specific Windows security functions.

Visual Studio's C-Run-time however, has some functions that 'emulate' (in a minimal way) the Unix security approach.  Look for _chmod and _access ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) should get you started).